# print random amount of words from a text file

Tags: node.js

I have a text file containing 100 words. I would like my programme to select a random number of words between 1 - 7 from the 100 words in the text file to print.

I know how to get a random number

```
var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) +1 ;
```

but not sure how to get my programme to select a random amount of words as determined by ranNum

```
function randomWord(){

   var fs = require('fs');

   var readME = fs.readFileSync('text.txt', 'utf8', function(err,data) { 
      //reads text file 
      console.log(data);
   });
   console.log(readME);

   //returns a random num between 1-9 
   var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 1;  
   console.log(ranNum); //prints out that number

 }

 randomWord();
```

I want my programme to select a random amout of words from the text file each time it is run

Comment: So how are the words laid out in the file?

Comment: @epascarello plain text : apple, orange, banana, pear, elephant, horse, dog, cow, brazil, england, france

Comment: @NullDev for each iteration I would like there to be a random amount of words between 1 and 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get `n` random words from a text file and the text file consists of a string like this:

```
apple, orange, banana, pear, elephant, horse, dog, cow, brazil, england, france
```

You can use the following code:

```
// declare 'require()' imports at the top of your script
var fs = require('fs');

function randomWords(words){
    // Since you use 'readFileSync', there is no callback function
    var readME = fs.readFileSync('text.txt', 'utf8');

    // Split the string into an array
    var wordArr = readME.split(', ');

    // Check if the specified amount of words is bigger than
    // the actual array length (word count) so we don't end 
    // up in an infinite loop 
    words = words > wordArr.length ? wordArr.length : words;

    // Create empty array
    var randWords = [];

    // push a random word to the new array n times
    for (let i = 0; i < words; i++){

        // new random number
        let newRandom;
        do {
            // New random index based on the length of the array (word count)
            let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordArr.length);
            newRandom = wordArr[rand];
        }
        // Make sure we don't have duplicates
        while (randWords.includes(newRandom));

        // Add the new word to the array
        randWords.push(newRandom);
    }

    // Join the array to a string and return it
    return randWords.join(', ');
}

// You can pass the amount of words you want to the function
console.log(randomWords(5));
```

I commented the code for clarification.

---

Working Repl.it Demo: <kbd>[**Demo**](https://repl.it/@NLDev/Random-Words)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! I've just tried but now realise that ranNum is picking a randon Num from the first 7 words. 

WHat I meant was the list has for example 100 words, I would like the programme to pick 7 random words from the entire list

Comment: problem is it is not a random set

Comment: Much appreciated!